# conversion of GetNextDocument() from old API- new API YAMLcpp

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I could not find equivalent code for new YAMLcpp version  `p->GetNextDocument( n )`.

Answer (score 4):

old API:

```
std::ifstream fin(config_file);
YAML::Parser parser(fin);
YAML::Node doc;
parser.GetNextDocument(doc);
```

new API:

```
  std::ifstream fin(config_file);
  YAML::Node doc = YAML::Load(fin);
```

Answer (score 0):

`YAML::LoadAll` or `YAML::LoadAllFromFile`

Comment: i would like to convert `YAML::Node doc;`  `parser.GetNextDocument(doc);`  into new API, 
     error: no matching function for call to ` 'Load(const YAML::Node&)'`
 
     `const YAML::Node doc = YAML::Load(doc);`

Comment: @abcd7, you pass your input data (or a file stream) to `YAML::Load`, or a filename to `YAML::LoadFile`.